# trying to save an array to ngrx state

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm trying to save an array I get from an api calling, using ngrx effects, then simply `*ngfor` that array. I'm trying to use ngrx but its making things more complicated. I am passing an array into the reducer but the state.comics is showing like this `comics: [0: {0: {..}, 1:{..}]`, when all I want it to be is like `comics: [0: {..}, 1: {..}]`j. So the reducer is not saving the array to the comics, its pushing to the 0 then creating more objects.

`comics.data.results` is an Array

action:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const getComics = createAction('[Comics] Get comics');
export const getComicsSuccess = createAction(
  '[Comics] Success Get Comics',
  (comics: any) => comics
);
```

effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ComicEffects {
  loadComics$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(getComics),
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.dataService.getComics().pipe(
          map((comics) => {
            console.log(comics.data.results);
            return getComicsSuccess(comics.data.results);
          })
          /* catchError(() => EmptyError) */
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private action$: Actions,
    private dataService: MarvelServiceService
  ) {}
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getComicsSuccess } from '../Actions/comics.action';

const initialState: any = [];

export const comicReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getComicsSuccess, (state, data) => [...state, data])
);
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let comic of comics$ | async; index as i">
    {{ i + 1 }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

component:

```
export class ComicsComponent implements OnInit {
  comics$ = this.store.select((state) => state.comics);

  constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllComics();
  }

  getAllComics() {
    this.store.dispatch(getComics());

  }
}
```

app.module:

```
 StoreModule.forRoot({ comics: comicReducer }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `comics.data.results`  is also an array.

so if you need to save it in state you need to use spread operator on it too. so it all can be one single array.

```
// Action
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const getComicsSuccess = createAction('[Comics] Success Get Comics', props<{ comics: any[] }>());

// Effect
this.dataService.getComics().pipe(
  map((getComics: any) => {
    return getComicsSuccess({ comics: getComics.data.results });
  })
);

//Reducer
export const comicReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getComicsSuccess, (state, {comics}) => [...state, ...comics])
);
```

Comment: what you're saying makes perfect sense and I already tried that, I get ERROR TypeError: results is not iterable, so it doesn't seem to be passing in an array into the reducer even though that is what I'm doing.

Comment: @artworkjpm you were correct I missed the point where in reducer you need to destructor the data to get what you need. I edited the code. hope it works ! and also I changed Action props. I don't know what you used but I usually use props for it.

Comment: thanks, it was using destuctors {} that seems to work, along with the props in the action.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you type your action. `comics: any` will shoot you in the foot, as it does now.

I suspect it should be similar to this.

```
export const comicReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getComicsSuccess, (state, action) => [...state, action.comics])
);
```